# Name for an inexact abbreviation

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, clipping

What is the name for a word that is shortened, but done somewhat incorrectly?

As an example, the word [***distro***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_distro) is shortened from the word ***distribution***, but with the trailing ***i*** changed to an ***o***.

Therefore, the word *distro* is a `________` of the word *distribution*.

- variant?
- corruption?

Comment: In what way is it incorrectly shortened? How is it different from any other similar prefix ending with an '*o*'? Why would you think *i* is the trailing letter? Assume that no letter has been changed, *distr* + *o* is *distro*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that no letter has been changed, *distr* + *o* is *distro*.

In what way is it incorrectly shortened? How is it different from any other similar derivation ending with an '*o*'? Why would you think *i* is the trailing letter? As you have yourself noted, *distro* is a **word**.

It is essentially a contraction, drawing *distr* from *distribution* and then modifying with a terminal *o* to form a new word. The second part can be thought of as somewhat similar to *weirdo*, from *weird*.

Therefore, the word *distro* is **derived from** the word *distribution*.

Comment: See also my comment about *clipping* at Harsh's answer. Yes, *distro* is one such clipping, used in the software, electric power, publishing and probably marketing domains.

Comment: This answer would be strengthened by references to outside sources.

Comment: But [contractions](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/contractions-american) are abbreviations too.

Comment: @Hugo: Yes, in the grammatical sense, contractions are abbreviations, too. I have edited my post suitably.

Answer (score 4):

It's a form of *contraction*:

> **contraction**, *noun*: a shortening of a word, syllable, or word group by omission of one or more sounds or letters or by the reduction
>   of two or more vowels or syllables to one [MW]

Specifically, it's a form of *apocope*:

> **apocope**, *noun*: the loss of one or more sounds or letters at the end of a word

The word *distro* is formed from *distribution* by apocope and *substitution*. You can see other examples of this [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=JXOd1wcA89QC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=apocope%20and%20substitution&source=bl&ots=ephcK51A2M&sig=6n5fOX2HL1vx6-UaIcfbBgXD0-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GfP0Ttm0LuKpiALoqomDDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=apocope%20and%20substitution&f=false).

Comment: However, 'here' is a title on Google Books. The book itself is not accessible from 'here', so no 'examples' can be seen at the link.

Comment: @Kris The link worked for me. If it doesn't work for you, go to books.google.com and search for [apocope and substitution](https://www.google.com/search?q=apocope+and+substitution&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). The book is _Word structure_ by Richard Coates, pg. 104.

Comment: Thanks, this one helps. The first link probably needs a Google login and you are signed into Google so it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have ever heard, there is no such specific term, so I suggest *corrupted abbreviation* as suitable.

Note, however, that in this example the *o* doesn't necessarily replace the *i*; the *ibuti* and trailing *n* are removed, leaving the *o* after *distr*.  I can think of a less equivocal example of corrupted abbreviation, though: *No.* as an abbreviation of *number*.

Comment: I believe _No._ is an abbreviation of _numero_.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a **clipped form**, or **clipping**.

[Read Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28morphology%29)

---

*edit*: To counter link-rot, here is the definition:

> In linguistics, clipping is the word formation process which consists
>   in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand:1969).
>   Clipping is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."

Comment: Another common form, slightly similar to this is called "Syllabic Abbreviation", as in the join of two words to create a new word, for example: Interpol (**Inter**national **Pol**ice)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation#Syllabic_abbreviation Read Here

Comment: Some useful info from this 'Read Here' reference: "According to Marchand (1969), clippings are not coined as words belonging to the standard vocabulary of a language. They originate as terms of a special group like schools, army, police, the medical profession, etc., ".

Comment: yeah... observing their usage, they generally fall in the colloquial or especially the **jargon** category.

Comment: Link rot happens, yes, even with Wikipedia. Could you include a relevant quote from your link (and also, identify what it links to)? @Kris' comment is a start, but many people don't read comments.

Comment: _In linguistics, clipping is the word formation process which consists in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand:1969). Clipping is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."_

Answer (score -1):

Abbreviation or "abridged form" or just "short for"

Comment: What does this have to do with the *i* changed to an *o*?

Comment: The i isn't change to an o - the i is just one of the letters removed along with b,u,t,n

Comment: Oh, I see; I wonder if the OP was thinking of that when he made his word-request.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, I think that's a stretch. The simplest explanation, and the one most likely correct, is that "Distri" sounds funny, and "distr" is unpronounceable, but changing the the *i* to an *o* makes the word easier to work with and plays off the fact that many people pronounce the root word "dist-ro-bu-tion", so it's believable.