# What is the English term for a word meaning a shortened/contracted version of itself?

Tags: terminology, contractions

I remember being taught this by my Literature teacher in school long ago but I can't remember the actual term, maybe complicated sounding like 'onomatopoeia'.

I don't mean apostrophes e.g. wouldn't.

An example is:
elongated = long,
where the second word can be formed by removing certain letters from the first word, and retain somewhat the original meaning.

A list of such words would also be cute.

Comment: some other examples: terminology = term, commentary = comment, another = other.

Comment: Tushar's suggestion does not fit. Read the article, kangaroo words are words which contain new words, like a Russian doll, or matrioska. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105107/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-inside-another-word/105124#105124

Comment: You may also be thinking of 'abbreviation'? For example, where 'Professor' becomes 'Prof.'

Comment: 'Elongated = long' is a contraction of the original word.

Comment: The term *masculine* "contains" the word *male* if you take out the letters -s, -c, -u, -i, and-n-. Taking "out" letters is not the same as *shortening* a word. An example: **advertisement**  can be shortened to **ad**. I have also provided [*kangaroo* as an answer in the past](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144020/word-for-no-i-in-team/145739#145739), so I'm quite familiar with the term.

Comment: I should have said "taking out *random* letters." I think your literature  teacher was talking about **apheresis**, a more esoteric sounding word than abbreviation, shortening or kangaroo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

...*where the second word can be formed by removing certain letters from the first word*

They're called [Kangaroo words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_word). The small synonyms are joeys.

From wikipedia:

> A kangaroo word is a word that contains letters of another word, **in order, with the same meaning**. For example: the word masculine contains the word male, which is a synonym of the first word; similarly, the word observe contains its synonym see.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed. A thousand thanks, Tushar.

Comment: @tech: My pleasure. I hope you visit EL&U again :)

Comment: I know the OP accepted this, but this isn't the answer, not to the question as it is posed. "a shortened, contracted version of itself" e.g.  *phone* is the XXX version of *telephone.*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: _" where the second word can be formed by removing certain letters from the first word"_ This is what made me answer

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Wikipedia clearly says the smaller words have the same meaning. Edited to include excerpt. This matches with what I remember reading in a fun-with-words kind of book in grade school, where I remember this from.

Comment: As a 39-year-old native [British] English speaker, I have never heard this term before. It's a cute term for an intriguing concept, but I've never heard it used — or had the concept pointed out to me before reading this answer.

Comment: @OwenBlacker: While in grade school, I found this awesome book in my library which had really cool terms for words with 'intriguing' properties. Like kangaroo words and [beheadments](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PVcHzENuAnMC&pg=PT47&lpg=PT47&dq=beheadments&source=bl&ots=1JihX3K0lA&sig=r-iPZW5ULfc6oHFBerStbGJ4NIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7JB1VcjmLoWG8QX2mYDQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=beheadments&f=false)

Comment: @TusharRaj Another term (and concept) I have never encountered before. What a great term. Thank you!  :)

Comment: +1.... for bringing to fame-a term-langushing in obscurity.

Answer (score 2):

The terms **shortening** (*make or become shorter*), *contractions*, *truncations*, and  **abbreviation** (*a shortened form of a word or phrase*) are often used interchangeably.

Take for example the word *advertisement* it can be shortened (or abbreviated) in two ways
 (1) **advert** (*an advertisement*) or (2) **ad** (*[an advertisement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ad)*)

Another example, **romantic comedy**   <sub><sup>*[(A film or play that deals with love in a light, humorous way)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/romantic-comedy?q=romantic%20comedy)*</sup></sub>
The two words are often shortened or contracted as  **romcom**

> **[romcom](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/romcom)**; informal
>   (In film or television) a romantic comedy.

The word *romcom* is formed by joining the first syllable of each word: *rom* and *com* together. In linguistics this process of combining syllables or two existing words  together is called **blending**. Examples of [blend words](https://books.google.it/books?id=lPdxvB8wAxgC&pg=PA48&dq=blend%20words%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NMx2VZXAIob8ywP77YLwDg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=blend%20words%20grammar&f=false) are: *brunch* (br+unch) which is *breakfast* and *lunch* combined, *camcorder* (cam+corder) which is formed from camera and recorder; and *escalator* (escala+tor) from escalate and elevator.

When parts of words are omitted, with no loss in meaning,  it is known as **clipping**

> **[clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28morphology%29)**
>      In linguistics, *clipping* is the word formation process which consists in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand: 1969). *Clipping* is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."
>   According to Marchand (1969), *clippings* are not coined as words belonging to the standard vocabulary of a language. They originate as terms of a special group like schools, army, police, the medical profession, etc., in the intimacy of a milieu where a hint is sufficient to indicate the whole. For example, **exam**(ination), **math**(ematics), and **lab**(oratory) originated in school slang; **spec**(ulation) and **tick**(et = credit) in stock-exchange slang; and **vet**(eran) and **cap**(tain) in army slang.
>
> <sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

The above in bold type are also examples of *final clipping*, or *[apocope](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/apocopeterm.htm)*, wherein the endings of a word are literally chopped off. Further examples are:

- photograph > **photo**
- English animation > Japanese アニメーション animēshon > アニメ **anime**
- street credential > **street cred**
- magazine > **mag**

When the initial letters, syllables or sounds are omitted from a word this is called **apheresis**

> [**apheresis**](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Aphaeresis.htm):
>    Also spelled *apheresis*. Adjective: *aphetic*. Also called *‘syllabic loss’* or *‘initial vowel loss’*.
>   Common examples of aphaeresis include *round* (from around), specially (from especially), and *spy* (from espy). Note that the deleted initial sound is usually a vowel.
>
> "Aphaeresis has given us a number of new words, like **drawing-room** (from withdrawing-room), **fend** (from defend; whence fender), **sport** (from disport), and **stain** (from distain). A number are *aphetic* in the narrow sense: **pert** (from now obsolete apert, going back ultimately to Latin appertus 'open'), **peal** (from appeal), **mend** (from amend), **fray** (from affray), the verb **ply** (from apply), the adjective **live** (from alive), **spy** (from espy), and **tend** (from both *attend* and *intend*). In the above cases, significant semantic development followed the aphaeresis, so that one does not normally connect in one's mind the shortened and the original longer forms."
>
> <sup>(The Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories, 1991)</sup>

---

Related:
[Can “sitcom” be considered an “acronym” [...]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/can-sitcom-be-considered-an-acronym-a-syllabic-acronym-or-a-hybrid-acronym/193830#193830)
[What is the name for the process which turned “iced cream” into “ice cream”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36609/what-is-the-name-for-the-process-which-turned-iced-cream-into-ice-cream)
[Is IOU an abbreviation, an acronym, or an initialism?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204086/is-iou-an-abbreviation-an-acronym-or-an-initialism)
[Name for an inexact abbreviation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/name-for-an-inexact-abbreviation)
[Why is “coon” a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244505/why-is-coon-a-word)

Comment: +1 for a very informative post. However, I still think the OP had 'Kangaroo words' in mind and couldn't think of better examples.

Comment: @TusharRaj   Quote: "a word shortened or contracted form of itself", no mention of *synonyms* anywhere. If you had also included *abbreviations* and *shortenings* in your answer, I wouldn't have felt so niggled.

Comment: Maybe not in the title, but the post does say _retain somewhat the original meaning_. 'Somewhat', not exact. Ergo, synonyms. Also, I didn't include words like `abbreviations` because it was too basic; not something the OP could have forgotten. I had a hunch he was talking about kangaroo words on reading the post, which, admittedly, lacks clarity. The OP accepted pretty soon, so I didn't offer more suggestions. I really hope you stop feeling niggled.